# Passing route values to Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want the form to pass the values from the hidden inputs to the server and I also expected it to build the URL as 
"localhost:9392/Ranking/Index/2?rankingType=SOMEVALUE&ageGroup=SOMEVALUE&week=SOMEVALUE"

but it shows like "localhost:9392/Ranking/Index/2?rankingType=rankingTypeID&ageGroup=ageGroupID&week=week"

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Ranking", new { id = Model.CurrentRanking, rankingType = "rankingTypeID", ageGroup = "ageGroupID", week = "week"}, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ageGroupForm" }))
                {
                <input id="ageGroupID" name="ageGroup" hidden />
                <input id="rankingTypeID" name="rankingType" hidden />
                <input id="week" name="week" hidden />              
                }
```

Why is that ? How do I pass the values and also have them show up as query string ?

Comment: The value will only be added as query string values if its `FormMethod.Get` (and you can remove the route values from the `BeginForm()` method). But what is the point of this - they are hidden inputs, not editable values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Ranking"))
                {
                <input id="ageGroupID" name="ageGroup" hidden />
                <input id="rankingTypeID" name="rankingType" hidden />
                <input id="week" name="week" hidden />              
                }
```

and in your action method, decorate it like:

```
public ActionResult Index(string ageGroupID, string rankingTypeID, string week){}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it shows like "localhost:9392/Ranking/Index/2?rankingType=rankingTypeID&ageGroup=ageGroupID&week=week"

That's because those are exactly the string values you're using:

```
new { id = Model.CurrentRanking, rankingType = "rankingTypeID", ageGroup = "ageGroupID", week = "week"}
```

It's not really clear why you're trying to set query string values for the exact form inputs you *already have*:

```
<input id="ageGroupID" name="ageGroup" hidden />
<input id="rankingTypeID" name="rankingType" hidden />
<input id="week" name="week" hidden />
```

If what you're trying to accomplish is to have those values be on the query string (as a GET request) instead of in the request body (as a POST request) then all you have to do is change your form method to a GET:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Ranking", new { id = Model.CurrentRanking }, FormMethod.Get, new { id = "ageGroupForm" }))
```

HTML form inputs are automatically added to the request, that's how forms work.  You don't need to try to do it manually.

Though it's strange that you're doing this at all.  Your inputs are hidden, which usually means you don't want to concern the user with them.  But you're also showing them on the URL, which may be confusing to the user (or may even be suspicious to the user).  You also aren't setting any *values* to those hidden inputs, unless you have something else not included here which does that?

Either way, your form will automatically include its inputs in the submitted request.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up a lot! I'm not sure why I thought the method should be post. Changed it to get and now it works marvelous. Thanks!