# How to create a partial view that posts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

i have created a partial view (a button that has icon) like this:

```
@model int
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="@Url.Action("Edit", new {id = Model})">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
    <span>Save</span>
</a>
```

but this one uses the GET not the POST. also, how can I get all of the value's that I typed from the textboxes as parameter to the partial view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565864/passing-route-values-to-html-beginform]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-You will use AJAX call for post method and return partial view like below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionForAjaxForm(FormModel model)
{
    // do something like save the posted model

    return PartialView("_YourPartialView", model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, It may help you.

```
  $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
            url: "/Client/ShowClient",
            data: "ClientCode=" + code/*{ "ClientCode": code }*/, //First item has latest ID
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#dialog').html(data);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
```

In Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowClient(string ClientCode)
{
    if (ClientCode == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    }
    ClientViewModel clientViewModel = this.Service.FindByClientCode(ClientCode);
    if (clientViewModel == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();

    }

    return View("ShowClient", clientViewModel);
}
```

for more details please see [Working example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-Partial-View-from-Controller-using-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)